# In JavaScript, how do I show screen progress indicator during an ajax call

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

JavaScript novice here.

I'm attempting to do something like this:

```
msls.showProgress($.ajax({
        url: "/Web/DataImport.ashx",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: file
    }).then(
    function success(result) {
        // Do something
    },function error(err) {
        // Do something else
    })));
```

Basically, I want the LightSwitch indicator to display until the ajax call returns. However the above code doesn't work, because showProgress is expecting a WinJS.Promise object.

Anyone has an idea on how to to achieve the desired behavior?

Yours,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
msls.showProgress(msls.promiseOperation(function (operation) {  
   $.ajax({
    url: "/Web/DataImport.ashx",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: file
    }).then(
      function success(result) {
      msls.showMessageBox(result);
      },
       function error(err) {
    operation.error(err);
     }))  
})  
);
```

Comment: your welcome dear! please mark it as answer if you get response ;) @user1533706